# ISO 7816-4 How to construct this C-APDU to write?

Tags: nfc, smartcard, javacard, apdu, iso-7816-4

I'm interfacing with a smart card (ISO 7816-4)

I have been given the below C-APDU to read a value:

```
CLA = 0x90
INS = 0x4C
p1 = 0x00
p2 = 0x00
length = 4
parameters = empty
```

Which returns the response 00000 2f4 9000

(9000 being what I understand to be the SW1/SW2, and the 2f4 part of that response contains the relevant data that I want to change)

Given this provided info, is it possible to determine what modifications to this C-APDU would I need to make to instead UPDATE this data (2f4) to be a different value?

I am quite new to this, and am trying to learn, so thank you for your responses.

Comment: As Andrew correctly states, this seems unrelated to ISO 7816-4, so you have to identify your token and get the data sheet. Updating is likely to be somehow protected, so simply swapping INS and filling in data will probably not be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that CLA of `90` means a proprietary command set and an instruction (INS) `4C` does not match any of the industry instruction commands.

Thus as this looks like a proprietary `read` command it is most likely that the `update` command is proprietary to the hardware you are issuing it to, so impossible to guess what it should be.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Is there a way of knowing whether the write/update would be under the same CLA? I assume the INS would definitely change, but I had thought the class would remain constant?

Comment: The only way of knowing what is supported is by reading the datasheet for this product. The could also support more industry standard commands, but with a custom read command it is more likely a update command to be also custom and in the same "custom" Class definition.